# UISwitch animation broken when embedded in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have observed that the switch animation does not always complete when the UISwitch is used in table view rows. The background of the switch stays grey instead of becoming white again. A [video](https://github.com/lukas2/uiSwitchBug/blob/master/uiswitch_bug.mp4?raw=true) and the image below show the problem. Does anyone know why this happens? This seems like a bug but perhaps I am missing something.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/lukas2/uiSwitchBug).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking this @scrrr, in addition to that — Clock application on iOS has the same bug with UISwitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a reusable problem on main thread. You can use the code below where switch action run on main thread async

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? Cell {
        cell.theSwitch.row = indexPath.row
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.theSwitch.setOn(self.array[indexPath.row], animated: false)
        }

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: This works! Ok so we have a problem in UIKit and queueing it again helps as a workaround. (This isn't the first time I see this solution for a UIKit problem. Cool that you brought it up.)

Comment: try to print `print(Thread.isMainThread)` above `cell.theSwitch.setOn` you will  get `true` so this isnt the problem

Comment: Sh_Khan: You are right but what his code does is it enqueues the call on the next time the main queue is executed. And this - somehow - solves the problem! In other words: the cell is returned immediately, and then, afterwards, the switch is set on. It is no longer set in "cellForRowAt", but later.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and this solution solved it for me as well. Any ideas why it doesn't work without async dispatch?

Comment: I had a similar issue where reloading the table immediately after toggling a switch resulted in this gray-background switch. Seems that the reload was interrupting the switch animation, so using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { tableView.reloadData() }` resolved the issue.